# How to make modifications work without restarting MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I deleted the slow.log of MySQL,but seems it's still cached in the system.

But I don't want to restart MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `flush logs;`?  [Flush logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/flush.html) "closes and reopens all log files."

Comment: Is this command the same as `apachectl graceful` of Apache?

Comment: It doesn't restart MySQL.  It closes and reopens the log files.

Comment: What if I made some change in `my.cnf`,how to make it work without restarting MySQL?

Comment: Some changes can be made dynamically with `set variable`, others can't be changed without a restart.  See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html